# circleci build test jar using maven and upload to jfrog artifactory

Tags: java, maven, testng, artifactory, circleci

I am new to circleci. I have a testng maven application with name autonotify, which has code both in src/main folder and src/test folders. So i am building jars for both main and test folders with below pom configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

This way my `mvn install` command on local generates two jars: autonotify-1.0.0.jar and autonotify-1.0.0-tests.jar. But, when i am trying to build jar and move to jfrog artifactory with below command in circleci config, it is building and moving only autonotify-1.0.0.jar.

`jfrog rt mvn "install -f pom.xml -Dmaven.test.skip=true" ~/artifactory.yml`

What is the way to build even test jar using circleci and move to jfrog artifactory? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I got it resolved with jfrog command: `jfrog rt mvn "install -f pom.xml" ~/artifactory.yml` by just removing -Dmaven.test.skip=true and it worked to create test jar with main jar!